# SQL Error "is not in the GROUP BY list"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to do a relatively complicated query that shows me what tags are used in conjunction with tag A, and it works on sqlfiddle but not on Bigquery. Here is my code:

```
select `tag_touched`, count(*) / numsessions as ratio
from (select s.`session_id`, `tag_touched`, max(created) as 
maxcreated, a.maxcreated_a, ss.numsessions
  from [TABLENAME] s join
       (select s.`session_id`, max(s.Created) as maxcreated_a
        from [TABLENAME] s
        where `tag_touched` = 'A'
        group by s.`session_id`,
   ) a
   on s.`session_id` = a.`session_id` cross join
   (select count(distinct `session_id`) as numsessions
    from [TABLENAME]
    where `tag_touched` = 'A'
   ) ss
  group by s.`session_id`, s.`tag_touched`, a.maxcreated_a, ss.numsessions
  having max(created) > maxcreated_a) s
group by `tag_touched`;
```

The error is:

```
 Error: Expression '`tag_touched`' is not present in the GROUP BY list
```

Any ideas on fixing this? Thanks

Comment: It's from the subquery aliased as `a`

Comment: ok I tried adding that.  "group by s.`session_id`, tag_touched", same error

Comment: got a link to the sqlfiddle for us?

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19585c/6

Comment: " ... ss group by s.\`session_id\`, ...." this works? I didn't think you could reference a subquery's aliases. (`s` is from inside subquery `a`).

Answer (score 1):

You have some minor errors in the syntax.  Perhaps this will fix the problem:

```
select `tag_touched`, count(*) / numsessions as ratio
from (select s.`session_id`, s.`tag_touched`,
             max(s.created) as maxcreated, a.maxcreated_a, ss.numsessions
      from [TABLENAME] s join
           (select s.`session_id`, max(s.Created) as maxcreated_a
            from [TABLENAME] s
            where `tag_touched` = 'A'
            group by s.`session_id`
           ) a
           on s.`session_id` = a.`session_id` cross join
           (select count(distinct `session_id`) as numsessions
            from [TABLENAME]
            where `tag_touched` = 'A'
           ) ss
      group by s.`session_id`, s.`tag_touched`, a.maxcreated_a, ss.numsessions
      having max(s.created) > maxcreated_a
     ) s
group by `tag_touched`, numsessions;
```

Comment: this returned "numsessions' is not present in the GROUP BY list

Comment: this is the correct answer - the difference is caused by use of quoted identifiers. put the numsessions column name in single quotes and it should work

Comment: ooops - just spotted you select this: `tag_touched`, count(*) / numsessions  but you do not include the count(*) division in the group by

Comment: This returns: "Error: Field '`tag_touched`' not found in table 's'; did you mean 'tag_touched'?"